# Regex for replacing times with comma to a dot in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a bunch of files in srt format, and I want to convert them to the webvtt format. Changing this `00:00:01,478 --> 00:00:04,020` to this `00:00:01.478 --> 00:00:04.020` works perfectly well (adding a `,` instead of a `.`).

How would I do this in Python? I made a regex and it "works" in Javascript detecting the occurrences: `[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},[0-9]{3}`. I am aware of `re.sub` but the documentation is confusing.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't suppose `new_document = document.replace(",", ".")` would work?

Comment: No, because the subtitles have both `.` and `,` as part of its text.

Comment: `re.sub("(?<=\d),",".",s)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use capturing groups in the same regex,

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "00:00:01,478 --> 00:00:04,020"
>>> m = re.sub(r'([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}),([0-9]{3})', r'\1.\2', s)
                 ^                          ^ ^        ^
>>> m
'00:00:01.478 --> 00:00:04.020'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
new_string = re.sub( r'([0-9:]{8}),(\d{3})', r'\1.\2', your_string )
```